# Moving an object along with mouse

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-1.1

i have drawn an square,now i want to move it along the plane following the mouse pointer.I am using open GL es 1.0.I tried to get difference in motion position with the below code:

```
@Override public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    float x = e.getX();
    float y = e.getY();
    switch (e.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
         mRenderer.dx = x - mPreviousX;
         mRenderer.dy = y - mPreviousY;
        requestRender();
    }
    mPreviousX = x;
    mPreviousY = y;
    return true;
}
```

and then i am translating the object by using gtranslatef function with dx and dy values.

```
gl.glTranslatef(dx, dy,0);
```

but for a little movement in mouse pointer.there is large displacement in object position.

How can i move object along with mouse?

Comment: are you getting you finger up  and pressing somewhere else on the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pointer coordinates usually are in screen physical dimensions, i.e. pixels. Your OpenGL coordinates depend on the projection and modelview matrices you apply.

What you must do is doing a backtransform of screen/viewport coordinates into your object or world space. This is done by reversing the transformation pipeline. Since matrix multiplication is a linear operation, you can not only put absolute values through it, it works as well for differentials.

I'd tell you more, but I need to say your existing program structure to give you sensible advice how to extend or change it. Please post it on http://pastebin.com or similar.

Comment: You can use gluUnproject function for converting your screen co-ordinates to object co-ordinates

Comment: @SatishKumar: Yes, I know about this. I didn't want to tell OP because I have a hunch, that OP might be abusing the matrix stack. First I wanted to see the code, to be able to make corrections on it, before coaxing gluUnproject into it.

Comment: I am sure you do. I thought, it might be easy for him to learn himself if he looks into the specific function. :)

Comment: @Abhishek: Please post your code at pastebin.com and I'll explain to you, where and how to integrate it.

Comment: It is availabe at " http://pastebin.com/ee1PQAtt".Please check it and post your comments.

Comment: @Abhishek: Yes I did. I just wanted to do an edit, but the pastebin went invalid. Anyway. I can tell you what to do: In your drawing function, right before you draw the geometry, take a copy of the modelview matrix, the projection matrix and the viewport dimensions (use glGet for this). Then use gluProject to transform the objects center position (just one point, and in your case probably 0,0,0) using them, and store the resulting depth value as well. Keep them around in some class variables. Then in the event handler feed those values in gluProject to unproject the relative movement.

Comment: Then add that to the previous object position.

Comment: Thanks datenwolf.I tried it on what you told.But still it is not coming proper.can you share draw frame code part.